# @media (max-width: 767px) { /*content*/} does not work

Tags: html, css, responsive

so i am trying to make my webpage responsive and a few days before i found that the main css modification that makes a webpage responsive is the @media rule
now the problem is

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .dropdown-content {
      margin-left:10%
 }
}
```

this part of the bootstrap-responsive.css which i refer as the tablet window version of the webpage is working fine. but when is switch to the mobile window version i.e. max-width :767px; the html page does not read it

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display:none;
 }
}
```

this part of the code is not read in mobile window version. what i want to do is utilize first css code above during tablet version and second css code above during the mobile version. is it related to some js file or am i missing something else? please help me with a solution.

Edit:- i have changed the attributes above and added some html code down here

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="policies.php">Policy</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <!--dropdown-content div-->
      </div>
</li>
```

By default the attribute of the dropdown-content is

```
 .dropdown-content{
    display:none;
    }
```

and when i hover at dropdown the following code takes action

```
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
        display:block;
    }
```

whereas in the mobile window version i want to hide it again such that hovering on dropdown does not show dropdown-content

Comment: Please add code sample HTML & CSS

Comment: are you sure it is not working? how you tested it?

Comment: it's not any css for `display:show` it was `display:block`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this `@media only screen and (max-width:767px){}` instead of `@media (max-width: 767px) {}`

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .class_name { width:200px; height:200px; background:#ccc;
      /*attribute_change2;*/
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="class_name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on expand right with "RUN CODE SNIPPET" you will find the working example.

See this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/) also..

Try this:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}
#main-nav li:hover ul{display:block;}
h1{font-size:25px;}
.navbar-toggle span{background:#000;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<nav id="header" class="container">
  <div id="navi" class="navbar-header">
   <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar b1"></span> <span class="icon-bar b2"></span> <span class="icon-bar b3"></span> </button>
    <h1 class="pull-left"><a href="#">BRAND NAME</a></h1>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul id="main-nav" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="policies.php">Policy <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li> 
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </nav>
```